# How to import .txt file into python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I have a text file with many values like

```
2.81,5.62
7.14,8.00
2.72,5.44
3.87,7.74
1.90,3.80
7.82,8.00
7.02,8.00
5.50,8.00
9.15,8.00
4.87,8.00
8.08,8.00
5.58,8.00
9.13,8.00
```

Now I need to read these values as I want to put the first value into an array `array1` and then the second value in an array `array2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read a file line-by-line into a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You just have to:**

1. `open()` file in read-only mode
2. `read()` each line
3. `for` each line in file

   4. `split()` each line at `,`
   5. `append()` first part to `array1` and second part to `array2`
   6. done

**Code:**

```
array1 = []
array2 = []

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        l = line.strip().split(',')
        array1 = l[0]
        array2 = l[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `readlines()` to read all the lines, and then split each line by the `,` character:

```
f = open('numbers.txt', 'r')
list1, list2 = zip(*[x.split(',') for x in f.readlines()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
my_data = np.loadtxt('poo.txt', delimiter=",", unpack=True)
list1, list2 = my_data[::] #unpack your array
```